# Visual Basic get data from a combobox

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

My code is now this, as i forgot to add the connection to my database after i updated the table, still doesnt work though

```
Private Sub cmdRegistar_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdRegistar.Click
    myConnToAccess = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = 'D:\PAP\LoginForm\LoginForm\bin\debug\login.mdb'")
    myConnToAccess.Open()
    Try
        Dim x As String
        Dim str As String
        x = ComboBox1.Text
        str = "UPDATE UserTable set Password = '" & txtPass.Text & "' where Username = '" & x & "'"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnToAccess)
        myConnToAccess.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

So as you can see the code doesnt have any errors, it compiles and runs just fine, it just doesnt work, the combobox values come from the same database of what i'm trying to do with the command update. All my others conections work just fine, my add, search.

Comment: Paste your code as text in your  question and wrap it in code tags. Explain what you're trying to do and why you think it's not working. Do you get an error message? My first guess is that you're trying to run a query but you close your connection before you do anything with the SQL

Comment: my database is in access  (2010)  i'm trying to replace a value in the database that comes from a textbox. no, not any error messages

Comment: Please retag your question to remove the VBA tag.

Comment: Never seen try/catch in Access 2010 - you're not using VB.NET?

Comment: i explained wrong, its vba, only its database is access

Comment: @JoãoMiguel this is **definitely not VBA**. Step one, know which language you're coding in.

Comment: it is? i'm using visual basic express to program this.. i never understood the differences beteween vba, vb net and vb6

Comment: @JoãoMiguel If you're using a **Visual Studio** version that was released this century, you're using VB.NET. If you're using Visual Studio 6.0 you're using VB6. If you're in a MS-Office application you're writing VBA. If you're in Notepad you're writing VBScript and I pray for your soul.

Comment: why pray for my soul? dont need to be rude jut because you have knowledge than me, thx anyways

Comment: @JoãoMiguel - MM was making a joke about people who still have to work with VBScript: don't be offended

Answer (score 0):

When are you actually passing `str` to your database?  Shouldn't you have something like `str.Execute` or something in there?  Aside from that, you also have an error in this line:

```
str = "UPDATE UserTable set Password" & txtPass.text & "where Username= '" & x & "'"
```

It should be:

```
str = "UPDATE UserTable set Password = '" & txtPass.text & "' where Username = '" & x & "'"
```

Comment: Sorry if it's a stupid question, but is there not a way to make a parameterized query and let the db engine deal with quoting and parameter valeus? I find it quite baffling that one would concatenate user input like this, as if SQL injection never existed. [**Must-read XKCD**](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: yes, this line Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnToAccess) [myConnToAccess = New OleDbConnection] but still doesnt work

Comment: Mat - Probably, but I don't remember much about VB.  In C# you would definitely use parameters.  Joao - That line seems to be missing from your post, unless I'm mistaken?

Comment: You have to create a data adapter to run this command.  See the example at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/308055.  I think Code Sample 2 would be the one you want to follow, and it does include parameterized variables as Mat referenced.

Comment: data adapater? i have read that article and understood almost everything, the difference is that is mySQL mine is access

Comment: Then the only difference would be the connection string.  You still have to create a data adapter and fill it, that's how VB runs the SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

*Password* is a reserved word, so try this:

```
str = "UPDATE UserTable set [Password] = '" & txtPass.Text & "' where Username = '" & x & "'"
```